# Adding a custom (Retina) image to a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, retina-display

Is there anything more required to add a custom image to an iPhone UIBarButtonItem than dragging a .png with an `@2x` suffix into the project (which is roughly 40 x 40px) and specifying this image in the image field for `Bar Item` in the attributes inspector?

When I do this with a 46 x 46 image it appears stretched and pixellated and doesn't look Retina-ish at all (see attached screenshot).

ps: I've attempted cleaning the build in XCode (with shift+option+command+k as per some instructions) and have ensured the suffix is lower cased correctly with '@2x' as per some other recommendations.

[image: screen_grab]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the 2 files to your project:

```
image.png
image@2x.png
```

then call it the same way on all screen densities

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

`UIImage` will determine the right one to use. If using IB, point to the `image.png` and not the `@2x` image.

Comment: Ahh thanks - it was the adding 2 files part which I'd neglected.  I figured I would add the non-retina icons at the end though just determined that both versions are required for proper display.

Comment: I played around hours with that issue. Finally I found your answer. Thanks for that!